# specific Rotating Algorithm in Java

Tags: java

im working on a specific Sprite Rotation Algorithm like in the Game Command and Conquer Red Alert 2.

If I click anywhere on my JFrame my tank rotates to that direction and if he has finished rotating he moves towards the destination. So far so good.

My Problem is that i cant handle the correct rotating and moving algorithm for all destinations.

Here is the method, which rotates by doing i++ or i--.

```
public double rotate(int soll){

    if(soll > ist){

            if(i==360){
                i=0;
            }
            if(i!=soll){
                i++;
                canmove = false;
            }
            else{
                ist=soll;
                canmove = true;
            }
    }
    else if(soll < ist){


            if(i==0){
                i=360;
            }
            if(i!=soll){
                i--;
                canmove = false;
            }
            else{
                ist=soll;
                canmove = true;
            }

    }



    return Math.toRadians(i);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, for all destinations? In what case does what go wrong? What have you tried?

Comment: @DrLove Do you have a sprite sheet of 360 images for all angles or you are using the same image and you just want to perform an affineTransform on it?

Comment: sry i gave an answer im new i didnt know that this was wrong so sry